# How to left outer joins with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have this relation:

```
class Action < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :actions_users
```

I tried to make a query like:

```
select *
from actions left outer join actions_users
on actions_users.action_id = actions.id and actions_users.user_id = 1
where actions.user_id = 1
```

Meanwhile, in my experience, in all of the result that I tried,

```
select *
from actions left outer join actions_users
on actions_users.action_id = actions.id
where actions.user_id = 1 and actions_users.user_id = 1
```

the join condition code and general condition are in `where` function.

How can I work it out?

Comment: the rails is latest version

Comment: For a better solution, see [In Rails 6, how do I add a condition to a left-outer-joins finder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387437/in-rails-6-how-do-i-add-a-condition-to-a-left-outer-joins-finder)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Because you have a general `where` condition, you can use [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations). This will generate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query:

```
Action.includes(:actions_users).where(actions_users: { user_id: true })
```

Or if you are using `Rails 5+`, Active Record provides a finder method [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins):

```
Action.left_outer_joins(:actions_users).where(actions_users: { user_id: true })
```

Comment: Just note that this doesn't add the condition to the `LEFT JOIN`, it adds it to the `WHERE`. They can sometimes produce _very_ different results. In order to add the conditional to the `LEFT JOIN` I had to write a custom JOIN with `.joins( "..." )`. I also found another way where you can add it to the `has_many` association but I found that less intuitive.

Comment: I downvoted because as the person above noted, it adds the condition to the `where` and not the `AND`

Answer (score 5):

Up to Rails 7 there is no way to specify conditions directly on an `OUTER JOIN`, see the documentation for [Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables). The examples shown are suitable for `INNER JOIN`s (as they use `.where`), but won't work for `OUTER JOIN`s for the same reason.

You could try to specify the `OUTER JOIN` manually, but will run into problems passing parameters:

```
Action.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN action_users ON (action_users.id = actions.id AND action_users.user_id = :user_id")
```

So you will need to do parameter substitution somewhat like this:

```
outer_join_sanitized = ApplicationRecord.sanitize_sql([
  "LEFT OUTER JOIN action_users ON (action_users.id = actions.id AND action_users.user_id = :user_id)", 
  { user_id: 22 }
])
```

And you could then use `Actions.joins(outer_join_sanitized)`. At this point you might agree that just running with raw SQL from the start is the easier way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a string in join query and use the rails table naming conventions for this.

```
Action.joins("left outer join action_users on (action_users.id = actions.id and action_users.id = 1")).where('action_users.user_id = ? ', 1)
```

Comment: Very bad example, never pass values into query text itself.

Comment: The `joins` should indeed use `?` parameter substitution and the `where` afterwards needlessly destroys the desired effect of the `outer join`, but this is still the somewhat best answer: At least up to Rails 7 there are no Rails methods using hash parameters that would be used in the `on` of a join.

Answer (score 1):

There is still no clean way to do that in Rails 7.1, but you could use ARel to make it work.

The first example to work directly in ActiveRelation, without switching to ARel:

```rb
  actions = Action.arel_table
  action_users = ActionUser.arel_table
  Action
    .joins(
      actions.create_join(
        action_users,
        actions.create_on(
          action_users[:action_id]
            .eq(actions[:id])
            .and(
              action_users[:user_id]
                .eq(user_id)
                .and(
                  actions[:user_id].eq(user_id)
                )
            )
        )
      ),
      Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
    )
```

or another version directly in ARel:

```rb
  actions = Action.arel_table
  action_users = ActionUser.arel_table
  Action
    .joins(
      actions
        .join(
          action_users, 
          Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
        )
        .on(
          action_users[:action_id]
            .eq(actions[:id])
            .and(
              action_users[:user_id]
                .eq(user_id)
                .and(
                  actions[:user_id].eq(user_id)
                )
            )
        )
        .join_sources
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Action.left_outer_joins(:actions_users).where(user_id: 1)

select *
from actions left outer join actions_users
on actions_users.action_id = actions.id and actions_users.user_id = 1
where actions.user_id = 1
```

Although you did not ask for it yet, ...

```
Action.left_outer_joins(:actions_users).where(actions_users: {status: 'active'})

select *
from actions left outer join actions_users
on actions_users.action_id = actions.id and actions_users.user_id = 1
where actions_users.status = 'active'
```

Comment: I don't see this behavior.... the `AND` clause of the `left outer joins` is missing, and the `WHERE` clause is present.