# In Rails 6, how do I add a condition to a left-outer-joins finder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, left-join, ruby-on-rails-6, finder

I’m using Rails 6.1.4.4.  I have this model with a has_many

```
class MyObject < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :products, inverse_of: :application, as: :item
```

How do I write a scope that does a left outer join and also adds a condition in the LEFT-OUTER-JOIN-ON clause?  I have fallen back on raw sql …

```
scope :awaiting_funding, ->(resubmissions: false) {

  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN products on products.item_id = my_objects.id and products.product_type = 11 and products.item_type = ‘MyObject’”).where('products.id is null')

}
```

But I would like to convert this to a more Rails-like finder method.

Comment: This is kind of a fools errand - in ActiveRecord you usually generate joins through your assocations and it doesn't give you a lot of control over the exact join clause. The query interface is actually for generating WHERE clauses. If you want to generate that exact join and avoid a SQL string you would use Arel instead - but I don't think you actually need this in the first place.

Comment: I'm open to any answer you see fit to propose, although not quite sure what you're getting at through your comment.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and used a raw SQL to solve it. I don't think there is currently an answer for this case in pure `ActiveRecord` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a new `has_many`

```
class MyObject < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :products, inverse_of: :application, as: :item
    has_many :my_object_products, -> { where(product_type: 11, item_type: 'MyObject') }, class_name: 'Product'
```

Now you can define your scope

```
scope :awaiting_funding, ->(resubmissions: false) {
   where.missing(:my_object_products)
}
```

This will create the query where `product_type` and `item_type` are part of the ON in the LEFT OUTER JOIN

PS: use a better name for `my_object_products` but you get the idea.

Comment: I think "{ where(product_type: 11, item_type: 'MyObject' }," is not syntactically correct -- you would need a closing parens ")", no?

Comment: Yes you're right, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for this. A little surprised you have to do this on the association and can't do it when constructing a query via ActiveRecord and `.left_join` or `.joins`.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a much generic example of [Left Outer Join](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins)

```
Source.
 select('a.*', 'count(b.*)').
 left_outer_joins(:b).
 joins(:c).
 where('c.body_parser = ?', true).
 group('a.id').
 having('count(b.id) = 0').
 all
```

Else, You can also use [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations). This will generate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query

```
MyObject.includes(:products).where(product_type: 11, item_type: 'MyObject', products: { id: nil })
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```rb
scope :awaiting_funding, ->(resubmissions: false) {
  left_outer_joins(:products).where(product_type: 11, item_type: 'MyObject', products: { id: nil })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This puts all the conditions into the WHERE clause, which is somewhat different than the original SQL I had, where only one condition was in the WHERE clause and the other were part of the "ON" condition in the LEFT JOINS.